# How to describe math formula by using xsd?

Tags: xsd, xsd-validation

i"m trying to validate if an xml element is a multiply of 5 by using xsd. does any 1 have an idea how to do it ?

Thanks,

Itay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you can't use general formula for validation. But in your specific case you can use a pattern match to match multiples of 5

```
<xs:element name="myelement">
  <xs:simpleType>
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:pattern value="[0-9]*[05]{1}"></xs:pattern>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```